# add automatically 2 spaces for html tags in `.blade.php` files

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

i'm currently learning laravel and while coding in vscode, it auto-completes the tags in `.blade.php` files (say, `<p></p>`). however, each time i have to add spaces in order to do something like this: `<p> {{ $title }} </p>`. how can i make put 2 spaces before auto-closing the tags? thank you.

my `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 15,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.css": "default"
    },
    "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.allowedLocales": {
        "tr": true
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
    "[commonlisp]": {
        "editor.fontFamily": "monospace"
    },
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/ankaraunifedaisi/miniforge3/bin/python",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.php": "php"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "blade": "html"
    },
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
      "blade": {
        "html": {
            "auto_close_tags": true,
            "indent_inner_html": true,
            "inline_break": 0,
            "unformatted": ["code", "pre"]
          }
      
      }
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "html-css-class-completion.enableEmmetSupport": true,
    "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
    "[php]": {
        "blade.format.enable": true,
    },
    "[blade]": {
      "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
  },
    
  
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [

        "xml",
        "php",
        "blade",
        "ejs",
        "jinja",
        "javascript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "typescript",
        "typescriptreact",
        "plaintext",
        "markdown",
        "vue",
        "liquid",
        "erb",
        "lang-cfml",
        "cfml",
        "HTML (EEx)",
        "HTML (Eex)",
        "plist"
    ],
    "php.format.rules.arrayInitializersNewLineAfterLastElement": false,
    
}
```

i need this to only work for `.blade.php` files. been spending time on it but couldn't fix this problem properly.

Comment: You may want to check this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shufo.vscode-blade-formatter